# Variable dentro de la funcion de un botón

Tags: python, tkinter

Compañeros necesito de su sabiduría.
Tengo definida una función para luego activarla con un botón.
Dicha función hace un par de cálculos, el problema es cuando quiero llamar a alguna variable fuera de la función que se encuentra dentro de la función no las reconoce.
`

```
x1=1 
x2=2
def boton0():
    x3=x1+x2
print(x3)
```

`
NameError: name 'x3' is not defined. la finalidad es tener un label que muestre en el GUI la variable y se valla actualizando constantemente (dicho label esta afuera de la función pero dentro del script, similar al caso simplificado que expuse).

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Francisco. Las variables definidas dentro de una función tienen un ámbito restringido a esa función y dejan de existir en el momento que la función retorna. Puedes forzar que se use la variable global colocando `global x3` al inicio de tu función pero generalmente es mejor usar una `StringVar` para actualizar el contenido del Label. Sería más fácil dar una respuesta más concreta si provees un  [mcve] de tu programa para saber dónde está cada cosa y de dónde proceden las variables usadas por la función.

Comment: al utilizar `global x3` tampoco me reconoce la variable fuera de dicha función en el ejemplo. Buscare una manera de acotar mi programa para proveer con mas precisión la dificultad que tengo (dispongo de la versión 3.6.4)

Comment: Francisco `global` solo fuerza a usar la variable global si existe o la crea en ese namespace si no existe en vez de crear una copia local en la función cuando se intenta modificar su valor. Si tu variable no está definida globalmente en el script cuando llamas a `print` (o llamas a la función antes) obtendrás el mismo error porque `x3` no existe en ningún lado en ese momento. Pero como digo, las variables globales mejor evitarlas, hay mejores formas, intenta acotar tu script si es m,uy extenso o no quieres mostrarlo todo y muestra el código, sería más fácil contestarte.

Answer (score 1):

x3 no existe fuera de la función. Para que la función te devuelva el valor de x3 tenés que explicitar que te devuelva x3 (return) y luego llamar la función.

```
x1=1 
x2=2
def boton0():
    x3=x1+x2
    return x3
boton0()
```

> 3

Comment: gracias, pero necesito rescatar el valor de solo la variable, no de la función ya que abarca muchos procesos.

Comment: @Francisco No se puede rescatar variable ya que esta es una variable local, solo existe en ese ambito. Posiblemente usar global es la opcion que estes buscando, aunque no lo recomiendo ya que ese tipo de variables son dificiles de depurar y viendo tu conocimiento en tu ultimo comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres imprimir el valor de x3 puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
x1=1
x2=2
def buton0():
    x3=x1+x2
    print(x3)
boton0()
```

Solo bastaría con identarlo bien, suerte.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]